# Select a subset from 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension

From a 2D numpy array `Z`, I'd like to remove certain points, at indicies `ix, iy`.
`ix, iy` are currently sequential lists of the x-index and corresponding y-index, like so:

```
ix = range(10)
iy = range(10,20,1)
```

So I'd like `Z[0][10]`, `Z[1][11]`, etc. put into a new list or array.

What is the best (read: most pythonic) way of doing this? Perhaps there is a better way of finding these indicies so I get an array of `[ix,iy], [ix+1,iy+1]`  etc.?

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179106/python-select-subset-from-list-based-on-index-set). I don't know how to use the list comprehension syntax of the selected answer for 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't test now, but AFAIK it could be done like `Z[ix, iy]` in numpy.
Also, you don't have to write `range(10,20,1)`, you can use `range(10,20)`

Answer (score 0):

```
[Z[y][x] for x, y in zip(ix, iy)]
```

(What `zip(ix, iy)` does is: make a list of tuples `[(ix[0], iy[0]), (ix[1], iy[1]), ...]`, i.e. the x and y indices for each element we need.)

Comment: This works too, but I had to flip the index to Z[x][y], which depends on how you define the x-axis. Thanks!